# Between every 2 real numbers there is at least 1 rational number.

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I am confused on how the following proof works

> given $ x<y $ If there is a rational number $r$ with $x+n<r<y+n$ then there is a rational number $r' = r-n$ between $x$ and $y$.
>
> We may therefore suppose that $1<x<y $. Let $e=y-x$. by archimediean postulate, we have $pe>1$ for some integer $p$. Thus $1/p<e$.
>
> if $\frac{k}{p}$ is the first rational number $>x$ then $\frac{k}{p}$ ought to be between $x$ and $y$, because $\frac{1}{p}<e=y-x$.
>
> to be more precise, let $\mathbf{K}={\left \{ n | \frac{n}{p}>x \right \}}$
>
> by the well ordering principle, $K$ has a least element $k$. Thus
>
> $\frac{k}{p}>x$
>
> But $\frac{k-1}{p}\leq x$
>
> Therefore $\frac{k-1}{p} \leq x + \frac{1}{p} < x+e$
>
> $\leq x+(y-x)$
>
> Therefore $x\leq\frac{k}{p} \leq y$

Why is it ok to initially assume $x+n \leq r \leq y+n$ ? This is seems to be nearly assuming exactly what is trying to be proved. (I know this assumption is in P=>Q form but nontheless I do not understand how this helps.

How does $x \leq r'=r-n \leq y$ imply $1<x<y$ ?

Basically after that I get the jist of it but I am really confused on why the proof started the way it did.

Comment: good catch, its been been a long day lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rationale as the following:
You *want* to proof

> If $x<y$, then there is a rational $r$ with $x<r<y$.

The author first proves (as a lemma, if you prefer)

> If $1<x'<y'$, then  there is a rational $r'$ with $x'<r'<y'$.

Once you have the lemma, you can prove the general theorem: 
There exists $n\in \Bbb N$ with $x+n>1$ (follows also from the Archimedean principle). Apply the lemma to $x'=x+n$, $y'=y+n$ and then let $r=r'-n$. You can then verify that $x'<r'<y'$ implies $x<r<y$, as desired.

Comment: perfect thanks for the help!

Comment: I feel a bit silly for asking this but since I'm learning this all myself I have no alternative. How does There exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $x+n>1$ follow from For any $M$ and $e$ be any two positive integers, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $ne>M$

Comment: Here is how I think a proof for this would go. If $x\geq0$ let $n=2$ thus $x+2>1$ so $\exists n : x+n>1$. if $x<0$ let $n=-x+2$ so that $x+(2-x)>1$. Thus again $\exists n : x+n>1$. In any case $\exists n : x+n>1$. But this relies on $x$ being an integer and so I am not sure how Archimedes comes to the rescue here.